# How to access the data attribute from a dropdownlists' selected item using c# razor syntax

Tags: c#, razor, razor-pages

How would I go about storing a selected items "data" attribute value into a variable using c# razor syntax? I only have a view to work with and there as no models or controllers.

```
    var brokerID = Request["brokerSelect"];

<select class="form-control" id="brokerSelect" name="brokerSelect" title="Please Select a broker" required>
    <option value="">- Select Broker -</option>
    @foreach (var row in brokers)
    {
        <option data="@row.ClaimType" value="@row.ID" @(brokerID == row.ID.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@row.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

The Request["brokerSelect"] will return the value of the selected item, but i need the "data" attribute value. I did look down the javascript route, but do not think this is possible as i need to do more with this value.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Data attribute values are not accessible to server-side code. You will need to use JavaScript to access the value. You can assign the value to a hidden field in the form, which will ensure that it is posted to the server, so long as the hidden input has a name attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" name="claimtype" />
<select class="form-control" id="brokerSelect" name="brokerSelect" title="Please Select a broker" required>
    <option value="">- Select Broker -</option>
    @foreach (var row in brokers)
    {
        <option data-claimtype="@row.ClaimType" value="@row.ID" @(brokerID == row.ID.ToString() ? "selected" : "")>@row.Name</option>
    }
</select>


<script>
document.getElementById("brokerSelect").addEventListener('change', function(e){
    document.querySelector('[name="claimtype"]').value = e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].dataset.claimtype;
 });
</script>
```

By the way, if you are using Razor Pages and not the older ASP.NET Web Pages, you shouldn't be using `Request["foo"]` to access posted values. You should be using ModelBinding:  https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding